# ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

Tags: python, language-translation

I am trying to translate a text to English, and I am using [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/#history) package version = 3.0.0, Python 3.8.5. But I got this error. I am using a company laptop and I don't have admin rights on it Can anyone help me with this?

This is the code that I used just for a test:

```
from googletrans import Translator, constants 
translator = Translator()    
translation = translator.translate("Hola Mundo")
```

And this is the error thrown:

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-93d54b4e73a5> in <module>
      1 from googletrans import Translator, constants
      2 translator = Translator()
----> 3 translation = translator.translate("Hola Mundo")

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src, **kwargs)
    180 
    181         origin = text
--> 182         data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
    183 
    184         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src, override)
     76 
     77     def _translate(self, text, dest, src, override):
---> 78         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
     79         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
     80                                     token=token, override=override)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in do(self, text)
    192 
    193     def do(self, text):
--> 194         self._update()
    195         tk = self.acquire(text)
    196         return tk

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in _update(self)
     52             return
     53 
---> 54         r = self.client.get(self.host)
     55 
     56         raw_tkk = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py in get(self, url, params, headers, cookies, auth, allow_redirects, timeout)
    753         timeout: typing.Union[TimeoutTypes, UnsetType] = UNSET,
    754     ) -> Response:
--> 755         return self.request(
    756             "GET",
    757             url,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py in request(self, method, url, data, files, json, params, headers, cookies, auth, allow_redirects, timeout)
    598             cookies=cookies,
    599         )
--> 600         return self.send(
    601             request, auth=auth, allow_redirects=allow_redirects, timeout=timeout,
    602         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py in send(self, request, stream, auth, allow_redirects, timeout)
    618         auth = self.build_auth(request, auth)
    619 
--> 620         response = self.send_handling_redirects(
    621             request, auth=auth, timeout=timeout, allow_redirects=allow_redirects,
    622         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py in send_handling_redirects(self, request, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, history)
    645                 raise TooManyRedirects()
    646 
--> 647             response = self.send_handling_auth(
    648                 request, auth=auth, timeout=timeout, history=history
    649             )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py in send_handling_auth(self, request, history, auth, timeout)
    682         request = next(auth_flow)
    683         while True:
--> 684             response = self.send_single_request(request, timeout)
    685             if auth.requires_response_body:
    686                 response.read()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py in send_single_request(self, request, timeout)
    712                 headers,
    713                 stream,
--> 714             ) = transport.request(
    715                 request.method.encode(),
    716                 request.url.raw,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection_pool.py in request(self, method, url, headers, stream, timeout)
    150 
    151             try:
--> 152                 response = connection.request(
    153                     method, url, headers=headers, stream=stream, timeout=timeout
    154                 )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection.py in request(self, method, url, headers, stream, timeout)
     63                         "open_socket origin=%r timeout=%r", self.origin, timeout
     64                     )
---> 65                     self.socket = self._open_socket(timeout)
     66                 self._create_connection(self.socket)
     67             elif self.state in (ConnectionState.READY, ConnectionState.IDLE):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_sync\connection.py in _open_socket(self, timeout)
     83         ssl_context = self.ssl_context if scheme == b"https" else None
     84         try:
---> 85             return self.backend.open_tcp_stream(
     86                 hostname, port, ssl_context, timeout
     87             )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_backends\sync.py in open_tcp_stream(self, hostname, port, ssl_context, timeout)
    137                     sock, server_hostname=hostname.decode("ascii")
    138                 )
--> 139             return SyncSocketStream(sock=sock)
    140 
    141     def create_lock(self) -> SyncLock:

~\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
    129                 value = type()
    130             try:
--> 131                 self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    132             except StopIteration as exc:
    133                 # Suppress StopIteration *unless* it's the same exception that

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\httpcore\_exceptions.py in map_exceptions(map)
     10         for from_exc, to_exc in map.items():
     11             if isinstance(exc, from_exc):
---> 12                 raise to_exc(exc) from None
     13         raise
     14 

ConnectError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123) ```

I used the same code on another laptop and I got another Error. I want to translate a text which I don't know in which language is(different files in different languages) to English and I am not sure this is the best package to use for this so even some other packages that you are using and you are sure that works would be great. Thanks
````